# How to bind IntelliJ IDEA random open ports to localhost only?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I run IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 (Ultimate or Community edition) on macOS, I observe that 3 random ports are open on all network interfaces (eth0, lo, ...). One random port is open by the idea process and the two other ports are open by a different java process launched by IntelliJ IDEA.

I've removed the only plugin I've explicitly installed which is SonarLint.

The debugger which is running on port 63342 is bind to localhost and this can be configured in the Preferences menu.

Here is the relevant part of the output of `lsof -i | grep LISTEN` :

```
    idea   3328    orto  187u  IPv4 0x3c332685aa6872fd   0t0  TCP localhost:6942 (LISTEN)
    idea   3328    orto  686u  IPv4 0x3c332685aa623815   0t0  TCP localhost:63342 (LISTEN)
    idea   3328    orto  752u  IPv4 0x3c332685aa676de5   0t0  TCP *:53212 (LISTEN)
    java   3341    orto   33u  IPv6 0x3c332685aa5f899d   0t0  TCP *:61070 (LISTEN)
    java   3341    orto   77u  IPv6 0x3c332685b9885edd   0t0  TCP *:53210 (LISTEN)
```

As asked, here is the relevant part of `ps -ef | grep 3341` (it's a RemoteMavenServer):

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -d64 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2017.1.1 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jna-platform.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/oromatcher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/lucene-core-2.4.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-server-api.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/archetype-catalog-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/archetype-common-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-lib/nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3-server-impl.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-2.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-2.10-shaded.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer
```

How to bind these three random open ports to localhost?

Notes

- An issue has been created here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175889.
- There is a question about this problem on the 
  [IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003409060-IntelliJ-listens-on-tcp-and-udp-ports-on-address-0-0-0-0-Why-Is-it-unsecure-)

**== Update 28 March 2023 ==**

With IntelliJ 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition), I have no more TCP ports bound to the wildcard interface. But two UDP ports are still bound to the wildcard interface as in the screenshot of [the CrazyCoder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43368412/1807667).

Comment: Please execute `ps -ef` to get process command line args to understand who and for what run `java` process.

Comment: Related: [Why does IntelliJ want to accept incoming network connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43444949/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't bind any ports on the wildcard interface by default, except for the UDP concurrent licensing check (only for Ultimate). All the ports used for internal needs (Netty library initialization, exclusive folders lock, built-in web server, debugger, compiler/maven/gradle/running process IPC) are open on the `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) interface:

[image: ports]

Comment: I should have precised that I'm using the macos version.

Comment: Please add the relevant `lsof` output to show which ports are open on `0.0.0.0` interface.

Comment: Thanks, I can notice it on Windows as well after a project is open. Our developers will investigate it, may take some time.

Comment: So far I've isolated the problem to the Scala plug-in. Do you have it enabled? Does disabling this plug-in remove the `*` entry from `lsof` output for `idea` process?

Comment: I've no Scala plug-in enabled.

Comment: OK, it's weird indeed. We've seen this issue on some of the systems and so far were not able to find the root case. Could be RMI subsystem in Java or Netty issue. So far we don't have an answer how it can be fixed.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni yes, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175889 for updates, sorry for the delay

Comment: Almost one year and half after, is there any news on this issue?