# Why does IntelliJ want to accept incoming network connections?

Tags: java, security, intellij-idea

➠ What feature in IntelliJ is acting as a server to accept incoming connections?

When first running IntelliJ 2017.1.1 I get a dialog box asking permission for incoming network connections.

> Do you want the application “java” to accept incoming network connections?
>
> Clicking Deny may limit the application’s behavior. This setting can be changed in the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences.
>
> [Deny] [Allow]

[image: screenshot of dialog box asking permission to accept incoming network connections]

Example of dialog appearing on a fresh install of IntelliJ 2017.2 Ultimate edition, in the New Project wizard, when clicking on the Maven tab.

[image: screen shot of Apple macOS firewall message asking "Do you want the application java to accept incoming network connections" in the Maven tab of the New Project wizard]

Why is IntelliJ causing this prompt? I got no such event when running NetBeans.

What exactly is the effect of denying or accepting? I am concerned about letting a Java process accept outside network connections as doing so is a  serious security risk.

Possibly related to:

- Question: [How to bind IntelliJ IDEA random open ports to localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43355834/642706)
- Issue [IDEA-175889: IDE opens random ports on wildcard interface in some configurations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175889)

---

This Question is *not* about the source of the message. The source is the Apple macOS [app-level firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall). You can allow or block an app from listening for incoming network connections. Allowing this is **a security risk**.

IntelliJ is asking to be added to the list of apps allowed to listen for incoming messages. My Question is, "Why does IntelliJ need to accept incoming network connections?".

[image: screen shot of macOS > System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall]

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43368412/104891).

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, but the question is why is IntelliJ trying to accept incoming connections?

Comment: @SteveKuo My Comment above was responding to a now-deleted comment by someone else.

Comment: What is the resolution to this? Did JetBrains do this to build in a backdoor to the application for remote access?

Answer (score 4):

Problably it is linked to the below.

If you click on http://localhost:63342/ you should be able to access the [built-in server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger.html). Which by default should listen only on the local interface.

[image: IntelliJ built-in server]

Open port in range 6942-6992 seems to be linked to [SocketLock.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/idea/SocketLock.java#L153)

```
myServer = BuiltInServer.startNioOrOio(workerCount, 6942, 50, false, handler);
```

*note:* Ports `6953, 6969, 6970` are excluded from that range. See [BuiltInServer.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/org/jetbrains/io/BuiltInServer.java#L41)

```
private static final int[] FORBIDDEN_PORTS = {6953, 6969, 6970};
```

Another open port is linked to a process `org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer`

```
jps -l | grep jetbrains
24628 org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer
```

You could find out open port with `netstat`

```
on Linux: `netstat -ltupne`
on OSX (something like): nettop -np java
```

and the related java processes with `jps` (as show above)

Comment: You didn't answer. at least not directly, what is the incoming network connection, and why should it be accepted.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The message in the dialog says "Do you want the application “java” to accept incoming network connections?". I would read this as an application is opening a port and the firewall asks if you want to allow connections to this port.

Comment: You're missing the point. Why? If you install an app on your phone and it asks for access to your contacts, the question isn't what written on the pop up message, but _why_ does it need such access?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Your example is the way around. IntelliJ want to listen on a port. And the firewall ask the users if they want (on the network level) to allow an incoming connection. The shown pop-up dialog is not from IntelliJ it's comming from the built-in firewall of MacOS.

Answer (score -11):

> as doing so is a serious security risk.

It isn't, unless you don't trust the specific product. And if you don't trust a product, why are you using it at all?

IntelliJ needs to check its license once in a while, connect to update servers, maven repositories, plugin repositories, external application servers you may want to connect to, ditto with database servers.

Netbeans needs the same, you no doubt just forgot you gave it permission at some point, or it uses an external JVM that you gave permission at some point.

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't need to accept incoming connections to do all the operations you cited in your answer. As a developer, you maybe sometimes connect to public unsecure wifi networks (starbucks, airports,...) and don't want to have unknown open ports on your machine.

Comment: This Answer is silly and incorrect. Silly: Ignoring the security risks of opening ports to incoming connections from outside the machine is either ignorant or foolish. Incorrect: As Lokni commented, *all* of your mentioned features require *outgoing* connections, not incoming. And ultimately this Answer does not even address the Question. I am reluctant to down-vote when someone is trying to be helpful, but I must here.